# Real Life example of build variant

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am an Android Dev, customizing application (product) for my clients. There is not much discussion about build variant on Stack overflow. So I just want to know how do you use build variant to create different flavors.

Example: people use this for

1. tab layout and phone layout
2. paid and free version

**When did you use build variant and for what purpose?**

Comment: Build Variant (Flavor) is very rich feature of Gradle. The core purpose is to make different app version based on single source code. For example You have a app for a Brand A and now you want to replicate same app for a Brand B with some changes then you can use Build Variant(Flavor). More info http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting to use Build Variants when you have to generate the same app with minor changes.

For instance, I an using it to customise my application for each of my clients.

For each of them I need to change some texts, urls, ... (in strings.xml) and change the UI, by either changing an image or an entire layout.

Comment: yeah true that's why i wrote that i am a Android Dev, customizing application (product) for my clients. But i different developer you use this in there own way.

Comment: I am currently working on this build variant. i know it will be easy for you. I can google it although . But let say i am interested in  "change the UI" can we change layout only without changing java files

Comment: @Shubham yes as long as it doesn't affect java code that you wrote already.

Answer (score 2):

One dimension of build variants is a build type. There are two default build types ('debug' and 'release') that are used to configure things like logging or not logging, using different API keys, etc.

Another dimension is product flavors. The definition of product flavor is 'customized version of the application build by the project'. It means that you can use the same project to produce different apps with minimal effort.

For example, one can make different versions for different countries (that might have different regulations), different audiences (age specific behavior), paid vs. free behavior. Another popular usage of flavors is in testing: 'prod' flavor for production dependencies vs. 'mock' flavor for testing dependencies (fake server, fake database).

This feature complements the ability to provide different language specific /device specific resources.

Comment: yes that will definitely save my time during testing on Live servers and demo servers. As i have many functionalities like GCM, Google analytics that depends on the file. and it is difficult to change during testing in LIVE and DEMO servers